# Mac App Sandbox: can't open folder in sandbox container with NSWorkspace

Tags: macos, sandbox, nsworkspace

I want to open a folder in sandbox container with Finder, but can't get it working. This is my code.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSString *folder = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Backup"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:folder]];
}
```

And I got this error message in Console.

```
CoreServicesUIAgent: Quarantine resolution refused to pid 4288 because it is not allowed to read /Users/username/Library/Containers/com.domain.bundle/Data/Backup
```

The folder is in sandbox container, it was created by my sandboxed app and I can write files into it, so I think I should have read permission. If I created this folder manually with Finder, then I can open it successfully using NSWorkspace. It's so strange.

What's wrong with my code or is there another way to open folder with Finder in Mac App Sandbox?

Comment: I don't think you can open a dynamically constructed url as you have. The user needs to select a folder and you have to store the security data that will be included at the time of selection. As I understand it, Powerbox adds security data to a url selected by the user, so if you're constructing them in your code then Powerbox won't be adding that data. And having said all that(!) I've been trying a similar thing to what you have with security-scoped NSURL's but Preview still won't open the file that a user has selected - I haven't tried opening folders but I imagine it's the same...